# JS Switch case in for loop not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to use `switch` case in `for` loop after the number in array got split but it doesn't work.

```js
number2 = 1003;
sNumber = number2.toString();
output = [];

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i++) {
  output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
  console.log(output);
  switch (output) {
    case 0:
      console.log('o');
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log('1');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
You cannot switch on an array. Try switching on output[i].

Comment: Are you sure you want to do a switch case on an array ? I've never tried that, but it's odd to me. Consider assign the value into a variable and switch that variable. Hope it helps

Comment: I agree with Pedro. Assigning a var ahead of the loop will use memory best. (i) could exist already, in my code at least.

Comment: @PedroMartins i'm quite new. Is there the better way?

Comment: Setting (i) to a var would help with scope. I NEVER use i outside of an algorithm. For me, it is safe. You just need to consider your scope. I think that's the warning. Let me know if you need hints on scope.

Comment: @JRodd yes i need a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is here.

```
switch (output)
```

fix as

```
switch (output[i])
```